# Facing an IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, train-test-split

I have been working on link prediction problem in which the data set, which is a numpy array, has to be parsed and stored into another numpy array. I am trying to do the same but **at 9th line** it is throwing an *IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices*. I even tried typecasting the indices with *int* but it seems to not work. What am I missing here ?

```
    1. train_edges, test_edges, = train_test_split(edgeL,test_size=0.3,random_state=16)   
       
    2. out_dim = int(W_out.shape[1])
    
    3. in_dim = int(W_in.shape[1])
    
    4. train_x = np.zeros((len(train_edges), (out_dim + in_dim) * 2))
    
    5. train_y = np.zeros((len(train_edges), 1))
    
    6. for i, edge in enumerate(train_edges):
    
    7.     u = edge[0]
    
    8.     v = edge[1]
    
    9.     train_x[int(i), : int(out_dim)] = W_out[u]
    
    10.    train_x[int(i), int(out_dim): int(out_dim + in_dim)] = W_in[u]
    
    11.    train_x[i, out_dim + in_dim: out_dim * 2 + in_dim] = W_out[v]
    
    12.    train_x[i, out_dim * 2 + in_dim:] = W_in[v]
    
    13.    if edge[2] > 0:
    
    14.        train_y[i] = 1
    
    15.    else:
    
    16.        train_y[i] = -1
```

**EDIT:**

For reference, The `W_out` is a 64-dimensional tuple which looks like this

```
print(W_out[0])
type(W_out.shape[1])

Output:
[[0.10160154 0.         0.70414263 0.6772633  0.07685234 0.75205046
  0.421092   0.1776721  0.8622188  0.15669271 0.         0.40653425
  0.5768579  0.75861764 0.6745151  0.37883565 0.18074909 0.73928916
  0.6289512  0.         0.33160248 0.7441727  0.         0.8810399
  0.1110919  0.53732747 0.         0.33330196 0.36220717 0.298112
  0.10643011 0.8997948  0.53510064 0.6845873  0.03440218 0.23005858
  0.8097505  0.7108275  0.38826624 0.28532124 0.37821335 0.3566149
  0.42527163 0.71940386 0.8075657  0.5775364  0.01444144 0.21734199
  0.47439903 0.21176265 0.32279345 0.00187511 0.43511534 0.4302601
  0.39407462 0.20941389 0.199842   0.8710182  0.2160332  0.30246672
  0.27159846 0.19009161 0.32349357 0.08938174]]
int
```

And `edge` is a tuple which is from training data set which has *source, destination, sign*. It looks like this...

```
train_edges, test_edges, = train_test_split(edgeL,test_size=0.3,random_state=16)

for i, edge in enumerate(train_edges):
  print(edge)
  print(i)
  type(i)
  type(edge)

Output:
    Streaming output truncated to the last 5000 lines.
2936
['16936', '17031', '1']
2937
['15307', '14904', '1']
2938
['22852', '13045', '1']
2939
['14291', '96703', '1']
2940
```

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: `i` is created by `enumerate`, so it is already an integer.  But what about `u`?  You haven't told us anything about `W_out` or `edge` (train_edges).

Comment: Yes, the error is most definitely in the right-hand side of the expression (`W_in[u]`), not the left-hand side.

Comment: @hpaulj I think I have misspelled saying "Data set". My idea is to parse `W_out` and `W_in` which are numpy arrays and store it into `train_x` numpy array. And coming to `edge(train_edges)`, it will refer to a single record or a *tuple* in the **train_edges** array, which will have 3 columns- *source*, *destination* and *sign*., hence the reason why I am trying to use `edge[0], edge[1], edge[2]`

Comment: That may be your intention, but which is it in practice?  No guesses or hunches allowed :)

Comment: @hpaulj you mean to say the code is not what I am trying to explain !

Comment: Does `np.zeros()` and `np.matrix(np.zeros())` do the same thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is causing the error.

Looks like accessing the edge object may be the issue. Debug using type() and len() of edge and see what the index error is.

implicitly specifying int(i) is not needed, so the issue will be in the assignment of train_index[x] or your enumeration logic is not right.

Comment: `[:3]` is valid slicing.  The missing start is assumed to be `None`, equivalently `0`.

Comment: edited after seeing it again, the int(i) looked strange at first.

Comment: @indigo_4_alpha, the `W_out[u]` gives 64 dimensional tuple output. The `out_dim` is 64. So, the train_x[i, :out_dim] is referring to train_x[i, 0:64]=W_out[u], where u is source node which iterates for every element in edge[0], in subsequent iterations. Everything seems fine

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @indigo_4_alpha, The error is caused by the 'edge[0]` element which is a string.

- **Code for checking the train_edges**

```
train_edges, test_edges, = train_test_split(edgeL,test_size=0.3,random_state=16)

for i, edge in enumerate(train_edges):
  print(edge)
  print(i)
  print(edge[0], edge[1],edge[2])
  print(type(edge[0]))
```

**Output**

```
['11635' '22046' '1']
2608
11635 22046 1
<class 'str'>
```

After observing the output, I noticed that individually edge[0] is a string. Then I realized that `int(W_out[u]` is of no-effect when `u` itself is a string.

So, I type-casted `u=edge[0]` to `u=int(edge[0])` in the lines *7* and *8* of the code, as shown below.

- **Master code for Train and test data split**

```
   1. train_edges, test_edges, = train_test_split(edgeL,test_size=0.3,random_state=16)    
    
   2. out_dim = int(W_out.shape[1])
   3. in_dim = int(W_in.shape[1])
   4. train_x = np.zeros((len(train_edges), (out_dim + in_dim) * 2))
   5. train_y = np.zeros((len(train_edges), 1))
   6. for i, edge in enumerate(train_edges):
   7.   u = int(edge[0])
   8.   v = int(edge[1])
```

Thank you one and all for sparing your time and giving me your valuable suggestions.